# Trying to find the number of nested elements for every parent

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
const mainQuery = [
{
  id: 1,
  type: "and",
  rules: [
    { id: 2, type: "condition", rules: 1 },
    { id: 3, type: "condition", rules: 2 },
    {
      id: 4,
      type: "and",
      rules: [
        { id: 5, type: "condition", rules: 3 },
        {
          id: 6,
          type: "and",
          rules: [
            { id: 7, type: "condition", rules: 4 },
            { id: 8, type: "condition", rules: 5 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       id: 9,
       type: "and",
       rules: [
         { id: 10, type: "condition", rules: 6 },
         { id: 11, type: "condition", rules: 7 }
       ]
     }
  ]
}];
```

Trying to find the depth/or count of total queries under every parent node.
For Example

1. mainQuery[0] should have total 7 conditions
2. mainQuery[0].rules[2] should have total 3 conditions

I am trying to avoid running multiple loops every-time. Can someone offer a better solution?

Comment: why not 11 for point one? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: It wont be 11, as i only want the count of conditions under any parent. (type=='condition')

Comment: There's no JSON involved here, just objects and arrays.

Comment: Better solution than what? There seems to be no solution to compare against. Please state what requirements you're looking for in a solution.

Comment: What is `mainQuery[0][2]`? `mainQuery[0]` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Do you mean `mainQuery[0].rules[2]`?

Comment: I only see 7 `type: "condition"` in `mainQuery[0]`, where does 9 come from?

Comment: Anyway, the solution should be a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? The `getNumOfConditions` function uses recursion to loop through all objects in the given object and counts the ones where the type is "condition":

```
const mainQuery = [
{
  id: 1,
  type: "and",
  rules: [
    { id: 2, type: "condition", rules: 1 },
    { id: 3, type: "condition", rules: 2 },
    {
      id: 4,
      type: "and",
      rules: [
        { id: 5, type: "condition", rules: 3 },
        {
          id: 6,
          type: "and",
          rules: [
            { id: 7, type: "condition", rules: 4 },
            { id: 8, type: "condition", rules: 5 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       id: 9,
       type: "and",
       rules: [
         { id: 10, type: "condition", rules: 6 },
         { id: 11, type: "condition", rules: 7 }
       ]
     }
  ]
}];

function getNumOfConditions(obj) {
  var count = 0;
  if (typeof obj.rules == "number" && obj.type == "condition") {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    for (var i=0;i<obj.rules.length;i++) {
      count += getNumOfConditions(obj.rules[i]);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(getNumOfConditions(mainQuery[0]));  // = 7
console.log(getNumOfConditions(mainQuery[0].rules[2]));  // = 3
```